# What are the consequences for building code violations of previous non-permitted work?

Tags: plumbing

In 2016, I remodeled my bathroom to replace tub with a walk-in shower and the work was not done according to code. The space is small and the distance from the center point of the toilet to the shower door is less than 15" (about 11"-12"). Now I am having the entire house replumbed and have asked the contractor to pull permits.

I am worried about what action the inspector will take when he sees my bathroom that was not done according to code.

- Will he make me rip everything out?
- Will he fine me?

Any advice or recommendations are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Will probably depend on the inspector and what side of the bed they got out of.  Have some nice coffee and cookies(homemade) and say it has always been that way as far as I can remember(almost a whole week).

Comment: Is the repipe just replacing pipes or a complete new plumbing system/re routing  of pipes?  Permit might not be needed(needs checking) if just replace pipe for pipe.  Are the pipes old enough for replacing(60 plus years)?

Comment: The contractor isn't your enemy here.  But the fact is, an inspector will be coming through to tire-kick.

Comment: Often, inspectors will not require you to significantly extend the scope of a project in order to repair existing compliance issues, but will require you to rectify issues that are within the scope of the current project.   Yours sounds borderline .... "entirely replumb" suggests a large scope, but if you are not already ripping out tiled floors or walls, you may not be required to do so.  If your inspector is aggressive, you could perhaps avoid issues by not "entirely" replumbing the area in question.

Answer (score 2):

I generally advise when in doubt check with the inspector, that person has the final say. In your case I would think about it, especially if you plan on selling in the next few years. You would not want it caught when selling forcing you into a remodel.

If you do ask the inspector, ask for a suggestion on how to repair it if needed, as you relied on a contractor that did not do what they were paid to do. I have done some remolding over the years and the inspectors only look at what was done at that time. I have asked about other things and have gotten good advice.

Comment: "Forcing"?   In most places, it would be up to the buyer to demand repairs or walk away.  The seller can remodel the bathroom, or leave the project as a "gift" to the buyer.  There's no forcing.  Are there jurisdictions (and in the USA?) that require minor code issues to be rectified on sale of a home?  By force?